# C: newline hex values

Tags: c, hex, newline

I've got some code which reads lines from a txt file and then does adds to a database.

If you type data straight into the txt file, then this is sufficient to recognise a newline: `if (ch == '\n')`

However, if you cut & paste out of Microsoft Word, checking for `\n` doesn't work.

If I dump out the hex values / characters one by one, the actual data looks like this:

```
2e .    [ Last char of line ]
 d 
58 X    [ First char on next line ]
```

The full stop is the last character on one line. The 'X' is the first character on the next line. The hex 'd' causes the newline.

What is going on?  And how can I test my `ch` variable against `> d<`, given that it's space-d in the hex?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe word files use \r\n as a newline, and the \r got somehow corrupted by the editor you're pasting the file in it. What editor are you using to create the txt file?

Comment: @Carlo  I'm using TextEdit on a Mac.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Windows uses a pair of characters to end a line: a carriage return (0x0d) followed by a line feed (0x0a).

You can write these in C as `'\r'` and `'\n'`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Hexadecimal literals in C are prefixed with `0x` or `0X`, so in your case you could use `0xd` or `0XD` or `0xD`.

Comment: using the hexa format in a string, it would be `abc\x00D\x00A_def`

Answer (score 2):

You can first analyze your data in the "Hex-editor"  and then you can get the hex values corresponding to a particular character and can also test the variable using those values appended with 0x.

Answer (score 0):

to space in hex editor simply write 0A and then 0D in the end of a line so that the next line will be in next line.